# Every $f : [a, b] → [a, b]$ has a fixed point where $f$ is continuous. Deduce the intermediate value theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, banach-fixed-point

Every $f : [a, b] → [a, b]$ has a fixed point and $f$ is continuous (on $[a,b]$). Deduce the intermediate value theorem.

I managed to show the other way, now I'm here.

I know that $f(c)=c$ for some $c\in [a,b]$, and I need to show that for all $x\in [f(a),f(b)]$ there is $f(y)=x$.

I know that $a<f(a),f(b)<b$ and $f(c)=c$.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Are you saying "$f$ is continuous" or "$f$ has a fixed point at which it is continuous"?

Comment: $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

Comment: Is this the original wording of the question?

Comment: We can assume $f$ to be continuous with $f(a) f(b) < 0$ and we need to find $c$ with $f(c) = 0$. This appears tricky as we need to find a function $g$ such that $g(c) = c$ implies $f(c) = 0$. This is possible if $g(x) = f(x) + x$. The challenge is to find an interval $I \subseteq [a, b]$ such that $g(I) \subseteq I$.

Comment: @alphacapture Exercise. Assume that every continuous $f : [a, b] → [a, b] $ has a fixed point. Deduce the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: The word "every" is very important here; also, I believe the problem is not to prove the intermediate value theorem for only functions $f:[a, b] \rightarrow [a, b]$.  I think it is to prove the intermediate value theorem in general

Comment: @alphacapture I see, it's because I did the other implication that confused me, I'm still getting nowhere with this one :(

Comment: Notice also that the $[f(a), f(b)] \subset f([a,b])$,and the latter is what you want for the intermediate value theorem

Comment: Do you know that every continuous function is bounded?

Comment: @GRS: Can you use the fact that a continuous function on $[a, b]$ is bounded?

Comment: I can see that every continuous function will be bounded by $[a,b]$ in my case

Comment: @GRS: The hypothesis "$f:[a, b] \to [a, b]$" is not enough for the purposes I have (and probably alphacapture has) in mind. As Paramanand Singh notes, we need to "tame" continuous functions that are not known to map some interval to itself. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I know that a fixed point exists, then I can say that there exists a contraction since $[a,b]$ is complete. Hence all these functions will map into a domain smaller than original

Comment: Existence of a fixed point certainly does not guarantee $f$ is a contraction...!

Comment: Be that as it may, here's a big hint: Show that if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous, real-valued function on $[a, b]$, and if $c$ is a real number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there exists a non-zero real number $\eta$ such that the function$$g(x) = x + \eta\bigl(f(x) - c\bigr),\quad x \in [a, b],$$maps $[a, b]$ into $[a, b]$. Now apply the fixed-point property to $g$. I've written up the details to my satisfaction (i.e., I'm sure this approach works), but hate to deprive you the pleasure of working things out yourself (which requires some creativity). :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks a lot :)

Comment: thanks to @AndrewD.Hwang. I was trying to find the form of $g(x)$ for sometime, but gave up.